# Long TTFB - Cloudflare

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, cloudflare

I'm running a website on Apache2/Ubuntu 20.04, and for some reason I'm getting a really long TTFB (~15 seconds), this only happens while I'm using Cloudflare's Proxy/CDN. If I'm connecting directly to my server's IP address (without Cloudflare's Proxy/CDN) (inside & outside of my network), this long TTFB doesn't happen.

[Network analysis screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ4jd.jpg)

In the image link above, you can see that Cloudflare returns a status "522", which means that the connection timed out, and Cloudflare could not negotiate a TCP handshake with the origin server. But the website actually loads after these 15 seconds.

On the same system that I'm running Apache, I'm running a html control panel called "Webmin" (not hosted in Apache), to manage my server remotely, and I'm using it with Cloudflare's Proxy as well, and the same thing happens with it, I get the same ~15 seconds for the TTFB. I think is worth noting as well that I have another server on the same network that is running Windows 10 with IIS as the hosting server, and I'm using Cloudflare's Proxy/CDN, and I've never had any problems with it. With that, I think this might be some problem with Ubuntu, but I have no clue of what could it be.

Here's what I've done already, but even after doing all of those things I'm still getting that long TTFB:

- Specified the Cipher Suite in Apache's configuration file.
- I've added all of Cloudflare's chained certificates (including Cloudflare's Root CA).
- Whitelisted all of Cloudflare's IP ranges in Ubuntu's firewall.
- Specified TLS/SSL version in Apache's configuration file.
- Checked and reinstalled Cloudflare origin CA.

The Apache configuration file & other archives that might be useful are available [here.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag6wulerepxEgY5W1XjFkFPhx_30Rg?e=uWeji2)

Any help is much appreciated!

[UPDATE]
After many days trying to get it working, I've figured out that the problem was the port that I was using (8443), which is [supported by Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Identifying-network-ports-compatible-with-Cloudflare-s-proxy) on every plan, and for some reason I'm getting this long TTFB. By the way, that's not a problem with my network or ISP, because when I run it on plain HTTP (without Cloudflare's Proxy/CDN) with the same port (8443), I get a "normal" TTFB.

Answer (score 0):

As you said with cloudfare enabled, (TTFB) is high.

Any firewall rules on the machine (Ubuntu) might delay the incoming request via  cloudfare to the destination server.

Try disabling the firewall & check whether it lowers the (TTFB).

Comment: Hi, I've disabled the firewall, and purged the cache on Cloudflare, but I'm still getting the same results. But thanks for the help anyways